# Segmentation Fault with a pointer to an object holding an unordered_set

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, unordered-set

```
#include <unordered_set>

class C {
public:
    std::unordered_set<int> us;
};

int main() {
    C* c;
    c->us.insert(2); // Segmentation Fault
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: menory is not allocaed for `c` object

Comment: wow. That was silly of me. Haven't used C++ in a while, can you tell? =P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a segmentation fault because the pointer has not been assigned:

```
C* c = new C; // <<== Add this
c->us.insert(2);
delete c;    // <<== Free the memory
```

Unlike objects declared as objects, not as pointers (e.g. `C c;`) pointers need to be initialized: you should either assign them an address of an existing object, or allocate memory for a new object using the operator `new`. Dereferencing uninitialized pointers is considered undefined behavior, often causing segmentation faults.

Comment: Or even better, don't make a "new" C at all, cuz you don't need to. Just do `C c; c.us.insert(2);`

Comment: The code in the question is not the actual code that I'm writing. It was the simplest form of my problem that still generated a segmentation fault. In my actual code `c` (which is not actually named "c")needs to be a pointer.